# CakePHP - How to allow unauthenticated access to specific pages

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication

I have created a CakePHP app where I have created a `UsersController`, which handles all about users.
When I try to browse `www.mydomain.com`, if I am logged in, it let's me see the index (`app/View/Pages/home.ctp`). Else, it redirects me to `mydomain.com/users/login` and persists to log in.

I have tried looking at `AppController.php`, `PagesController.php` or `app/Config/core.php` and `app/Config/routes.php`, but did not find anything. My `UsersController.php`, also, is not responsible for that, I think.

I do not remember and I cannot find how to disable this. Which file should be responsible for that?

EDIT:my CakePHP version is 2.3.

Comment: For me this sounds like the auth components correct default behavior, if not logged in, you are being redirected to `/users/login`. So what is it that you want to disable? The need to login at all?

Comment: i want to disable the need to login when i browse under mydomain.com. cause i want guests also to see my home page and not being obliged to log in.

Comment: I see. btw, it's always good to specify things like this in your question, just like the use of the auth component and your specific CakePHP version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you can make specific actions public using the [auth components `allow()` method](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#making-actions-public).

Making pages public may require a little more work in case you'd want to make only specific pages public, since the `PagesController` handles all pages in a single action (`display()`). If that is the case, then you could utilize `request->params['pass'][0]` which will hold the page name, test this against a list of allowed pages, and then allow the `display` action using `Auth::allow`.

Example, in the `PagesController`:

```
public function beforeFilter()
{
    parent::beforeFilter();

    $allowedPages = array('home', 'foo', 'bar');
    if(isset($this->request->params['pass'][0]) &&
       in_array($this->request->params['pass'][0], $allowedPages))
    {
        $this->Auth->allow('display');
    }
}
```

This would allow the pages `home`, `foo` and `bar` to be viewed without being logged in.

If you'd wanted to make *all* pages public, then you could simply use `Auth::allow` without any conditions, ie:

```
public function beforeFilter()
{
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('display');
}
```

Comment: Thank you that worked!!! also with your explanations i got many things i hadn't cleared in my mind,thanks!!!

Comment: In CakePHP 4, request params are protected and cannot be used.

Comment: @cslotty In 4.x you can use [**`getParam()`**](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/controllers/request-response.html#request-parameters), like `$this->request->getParam('pass')[0]`, and you should consider using the [**authentication plugin**](https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/2/en/index.html) instead of the deprecated auth component.