# cakePHP Exclude PagesController Action from Auth

Tags: php, html, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

Hi first of all I'm using cakePHP 2.3.x

I'm having problem excluding my view pages from authentication. For example I have my static home page in Pages/home.ctp

In my AppController and PagesController I putted:

```
public function beforeFilter() {

        $this->Auth->allow('home');
        //$this->Auth->deny('add','edit','delete','index');
```

}

Yet it still requires me to log in.

I also putted in my PagesController

```
public function home(){

}
```

But still no luck.

Any help will be appriciated

Comment: Careful with the Pages controller, it is a special one. All pages are usually grouped under the action "display", so you would need to whitelist this action, instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CakePHP persists to log in when browsing app's index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18015096/cakephp-persists-to-log-in-when-browsing-apps-index)

Answer (score 0):

please try with this in pages controller

```
public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow("*");
    }
```

OR try with `$this->Auth->allow("display");`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using PagesController I **created a copy** of it and name it with another name. I just `deleted the display()` function and put all other action there, and `created the view` and it runs good. I guest you can't just put a lot in PagesController.

Comment: you should go with the other answer