# CakePHP AuthComponent how to allow specific view

Tags: php, cakephp

I want that my home (View/Pages/home.ctp) to become a public view, cause everytime I try to access, redirects me to /users/login..
AppController.php:

```
public $components = array(
      'Session',
      'Auth' => array(
         'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'areaRestrita'),
         'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'logout'),
            'authError' => 'Você deve fazer login para ter acesso a essa área!',
            'loginError'=> 'Combinação de usuário e senha errada!'
      )
    );
```

BeforeFilter:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow( 'index' );
    }
```

What should I do? I tried to put a beforeFilter at pagesController.php to allow('display') but doesn't works.

Comment: Can you put your `beforefilter` callback code ..

Comment: possible duplicate of [CakePHP persists to log in when browsing app's index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18015096/cakephp-persists-to-log-in-when-browsing-apps-index)

Comment: I had not seen it, thanks bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You allow actions not views using Auth. The default Pages controller of CakePHP uses the same `display()` action to render all static views. So if you want to allow just the homepage either make a separate action for it and route "/" to that action, or in `beforeFilter()` use `$this->request->params` to check if the request is for homepage and use `$this->Auth->allow()`.

Comment: How could I use the second way? I tried to put this `$this->Auth->allow($this->request->params['requested']);` at beforeFilter in Pages and is not working.

Comment: `Auth->allow()` takes action name (or no argument). `$this->request->params['requested']` is not an action name.

Comment: Action comes from a Controller? So, I have to create a Controller to every page that I want that unlogged users see? Sorry, I'm newbie to this.

Comment: I suggest you read the CakePHP manual and understand the basic of a controller and how a request is handled.

Comment: Oh, I used allow without arguments and that worked! thanks buddy