# Cakephp Auth->Allow not allowing actions without login

Tags: cakephp, authentication

I have a page called `about_us` in `pages` controller. I want it to be visible to everyone, so I wrote in `AppController.php`:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->allow('about_us','login');
}
```

But when I wanted to visit `contact_us` page `url/pages/about_us`, it says:

> You are not authorized to access that location. How can I add the action to be able to visible to everyone?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CakePHP persists to log in when browsing app's index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18015096/cakephp-persists-to-log-in-when-browsing-apps-index)

Comment: if you want to make `url/pages/contact_us visivle`, add `contact_us` to `$this->Auth->allow();` : `$this->Auth->allow('about_us','login','contact_us');`

Comment: @SimontheSourcecoderer which will do precisely nothing. Nitish it doesn't work because your users contorller _isn't used_ for requests handled by the pages controller (think about it), moreover the controller action is called display.

Answer (score 1):

In Allow you have to pass action name in array

You can use following code to allow more than one action

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->allow(array('about_us','login'));
}
```

Comment: There is no any problem without array !!It will work without array();

Answer (score 0):

In your app controller, do something like this:

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event) {
    parent::beforeFilter($event);
    $this->Auth->allow(['controller' => 'yourcontroller', 'action' => 'youraction']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make shure your `beforeFilter()` function of your AppController is called somewhere e.g. in the `beforeFilter()` of your PagesController:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You need create `beforeFilter` in `PageController.php`

```
public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow('about_us');
    }
```

Comment: should be `PagesController` and not `PageController`. Also there's not a `about_us` action to allow in `PagesController` because all pages are handled by `display` action. See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18018739/2776508